# Find the count of each category in a dataframe for uniques value of third column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe `df1`:

```
A|A2|A3
-+--+--
a|ut|x
a|tv|y
a|ut|x
a|pq|y
a|ut|y
b|st|x
b|qp|x
b|nt|y
c|st|x
c|st|x
c|st|y
c|st|z
```

I want to know the frequency of `A2` with unique `A3` for each `A`, i.e. I want following output:

```
A|A2|freq
-+--+----
a|ut|2
a|tv|1
a|pq|1
b|st|1
b|qp|1
b|nt|1
c|st|3
```

I tried

```
count(df1, A, A2, A3)
```

but get the error

> Error in count(df1, A, A2, A3)  :  unused argument A3

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr, you can use `distinct` to remove duplicated rows, then `count` to aggregate:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data_frame(A = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"), 
                  A2 = c("ut", "tv", "ut", "pq", "ut", "st", "qp", "nt", "st", "st", "st", "st"), 
                  A3 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z"))

df2 <- df1 %>% distinct() %>% count(A, A2)

df2
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>       A    A2     n
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1     a    pq     1
#> 2     a    tv     1
#> 3     a    ut     2
#> 4     b    nt     1
#> 5     b    qp     1
#> 6     b    st     1
#> 7     c    st     3
```

or more generalizably, use `n_distinct`:

```r
df1 %>% group_by(A, A2) %>% summarise(freq = n_distinct(A3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(freq = uniqueN(A3)), .(A, A2)]
#   A A2 freq
#1: a ut    2
#2: a tv    1
#3: a pq    1
#4: b st    1
#5: b qp    1
#6: b nt    1
#7: c st    3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c", "c"), A2 = c("ut", "tv", "ut", "pq", "ut", "st", 
 "qp", "nt", "st", "st", "st", "st"), A3 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", 
"y", "x", "x", "y", "x", "x", "y", "z")), .Names = c("A", "A2", 
"A3"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` for this:

```
> aggregate(A3 ~ A+A2, data=df1, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
  A A2 A3
1 b nt  1
2 a pq  1
3 b qp  1
4 b st  1
5 c st  3
6 a tv  1
7 a ut  2
```